# How can I use errorhandler in nodejs connect

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I`ve tried to use errorhandler, but there is no deference between using errorhandler or not.
I wonder how to use errorhandler module in nodejs.

```
var app = connect();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  console.log('development on');
  app.use(errorhandler({log: errorNotification}));
}

function errorNotification(err, str, req) {
  var title = 'Error in ' + req.method + ' ' + req.url;
  console.log('title');
}

app.use( function (req,res) {
   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   aaaaa(); //to invoke Reference error
   res.end('Not Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `connect` applies middlewares in the order you registered them. So, your `errorhandler` can only handle errors from previously registered middlewares. In most cases error handling middleware should be the last one:

```
app.use( function (req,res) {
  // whatever
});

app.use(errorhandler({log: errorNotification}));
```